# redis fails to connect in rails (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

learning different ways of doing autofill suggestions in Rails. now, trying out Redis, based on Railscast 399, and the rake task stopped working.

controller:

```
class VenueSuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    VenueSuggestion.create(params[:venue_suggestion])
  end

  def index
    render json: VenueSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
  end

  private
        def venue_suggestion_params
            params.require(:venue_suggestion).permit(:term, :popularity, venues_attributes: [ :id, :name, :address ])
        end
end
```

model

```
class VenueSuggestion
  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    $redis.zrevrange "venue-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 0, 9
  end

  def self.index_venues
    Venue.find_each do |venue|
      index_term(venue.name)
      index_term(venue.address)
      venue.name.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
    end
  end

  def self.index_term(term)
    1.upto(term.length-1) do |n|
      prefix = term[0, n]
      $redis.zincrby "venue-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 1, term.downcase
    end
  end
end
```

rake task:

```
namespace :venue_suggestions do
  desc "Generate venue suggestions for event form"
  task :index => :environment do
    VenueSuggestion.index_venues
  end
end
```

config/initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new
```

and then trying to run it:

```
$ rake venue_suggestions:index --trace
** Invoke venue_suggestions:index (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute venue_suggestions:index
rake aborted!
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Comment: can you also include where $redis is defined?

Comment: This error usually only occurs either if your redis-server is not running or your are running on a different port.

Comment: ok, so it works if I run `redis-server` in a separate window, but is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, what you are looking to do is run your redis-server in the background.

*The Easy Way(Tm)*

```
redis-server &
```

*The Proper Way(Tm)*

```
# cd into your redis directory(path for mine on OSX below)
cd /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
vim redis.conf
daemonize yes # find this line and change 'no' to 'yes'
```

Then restart your redis server.

Also, here are helpful instructions specific to OSX(if that's your platform):
https://medium.com/@petehouston/install-and-config-redis-on-mac-os-x-via-homebrew-eb8df9a4f298#.mc9tqg22p